# How to check if device supports Apple wallet or not in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, passkit, apple-wallet

I want to disable adding to Apple wallet if its an iPad. So I used this:

```
 var passKitProxy: PassKitProxyProtocol! { get set }

 if !passKitProxy.isPassLibraryAvailable {
 print("Doesn't support Apple wallet") 
 } else {
 print("Supports Apple wallet")
 }
```

This doesn't show Apple wallet option in iPad Simulator but shows in real iPad device. I think its because iPad simulator doesn't have Apple wallet app in it where as iPad device has. How do I disable apple wallet for iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `passKitProxy.isPassLibraryAvailable`, is a wrapper for [`isPassLibraryAvailable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpasslibrary/1617080-ispasslibraryavailable) then this is not a valid approach to check if passes can be added.

From the documentation for `isPassLibraryAvailable` -

> **Note**
> Don’t use this method to determine whether the user can add passes on the device. A device may have a pass library, but still not be able to add passes. Use the PKAddPassesViewController class’s canAddPasses() method instead.

You should use something like:

```
if PKAddPassesViewController.canAddPasses() {
    print("Can add passes") 
} else {
    print("Cannot add passes") 
}
```

Comment: Just curious, which devices cannot add passes?

Comment: iPad devices for one, as per the question.

Comment: Yes, and M1 Macs. Any phones or ipods? All the ones I tried seemed to work in the simulator. I may not have checked an ipod.